# Alter column's default value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000, default

I  have a table which has a column 'CompanyID int not null' and its default value is set to 10. Now I want to write a query which will alter this default value to 1. How can can I do it?

Any help will be appreciated. I am using SQL server 2000.

Comment: Are you saying you wish to set the rows which have been defaulted to 10 to a new value?  (In which case you may find it hard to tell the difference between a row that has been defaulted to 10 and a row that has been manually set to 10.)

Comment: There are not entry in the table. I want to change the CompanyID column default value to 1.so that every time i insert data in the table , it should automatically insert 1 in the CompanyID column.Earlier the default value is set through constraint.

Answer (score 17):

I think the best you can do is drop the constraint and create it again:

```
alter table dbo.yourTable
drop constraint default_value_name_constraint
go
alter table dbo.yourTable
add constraint default_value_name_constraint default YourValue for ColumnName
go
```

Answer (score 9):

First, find out the name of the 'constraint' on the field which is used to set the default. You can do this by running this query:

```
EXEC sp_helpconstraint 'MyTable'
```

Then, you can just drop and re-add the constraint.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable
DROP CONSTRAINT def_MyTable_CompanyID
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable
ADD CONSTRAINT def_MyTable_CompanyID DEFAULT (1) FOR CompanyID
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ALTER COLUMN CompanyID SET DEFAULT 1;
```

Comment: I have tried this, it is not working.The error is 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SET'.'

Answer (score -1):

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ALTER COLUMN CompanyID SET DEFAULT Pending;
```

I have tried this in mysql and it was giving error near Pending

Then I tried

```
 ALTER TABLE tablename ALTER COLUMN CompanyID SET DEFAULT 'Pending';
```

which worked fine.